# How do I get the latest job completed date for a premises that also has a blank completion date for a more recent job?

Tags: sql-server, null, max

The (stripped-down) job table has fields: job.id, job.premises_id, job.completed_date

I need to know premises where job.completed_date is null (a job has been booked but not yet completed) the output must include max(job.completed_date) for that premises (the date of the most recent job that has been completed at that premises.

I tried:

```sql
SELECT job.premises_id
, job.jobid
,(SELECT MAX(job.completed_date) FROM job where job.completed_date IS NOT NULL) as 'last job'

FROM job

WHERE job.completed_date is null
```

Comment: I don't really follow the logic here. if you want to know premisis where `job.completed_date` has the value `NULL` how can `MAX(job.completed_date)` have any other value than `NULL`..?

Comment: There are many job records for the same premises. The query needs to find a premises with a NULL completed_date, then find another job record for the same premises where the job has been completed, return the max value to get the most recent completed job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a CTE with a partitioned aggregate?

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT j.premises_id,
           j.jobid,
           j.completed_date,
           MAX(j.completed_date) OVER (PARTITION BY j.premises_id) AS MaxCompletedDate
    FROM dbo.job j)
SELECT premises_id,
       jobid,
       MaxCompletedDate
FROM CTE
WHERE completed_date IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you Larnu. I needed to either remove the 'j.' or add j to the FROM dbo.job. the output is giving me dates in the MaxCompletedDate column. I now need to check that these are the latest dates.  At first sight it looks like a solution though.

Comment: Sorry missed the alias in the `FROM`; easy mistake when you can't run the code.

Comment: This solves it, happy days. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Sample data will help your question but assuming you can have multiple rows for a *jobid* you need to include a *correlation* in the subquery; *Max* already excludes null values.

```
select j.premises_id, j.jobid, (
    select Max(j2.completed_date) 
      from job j2
      where j2.jobId = j.JobId
  ) as [last job]
from job j
where j.completed_date is null;
```

You may need to also include *premises_id* in the correlation. Also note delimiters should be either square brackets or double quotes.

Comment: Thanks Stu. I assume "where j.job.completed_date" should be "where j.completed_date".  I had forgotten about correlations. I tried what you suggested, it is returning the NULLS, rather than the lasted completed_date. I am being diverted from this to another job. I will check my implementation later.

Comment: Ah yes I must have missed that - edited.